A hyperlink is not rendered in a question body -- is it a markdown rendering bug?
More than $4$ years after posting this question I got a comment that it's better to include hyperlink to the Crux source, but the link has been there in the question all the time, it just stopped to render.
Neither works this [Crux Vol. 1, No. 7][1] (pp. 64-66)
[1]: https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=1&issue=7
nor this
[Crux Vol. 1, No. 7](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=1&issue=7) (pp. 64-66)
(to say, both ways are fine in the question body on meta).
So is it a bug or something? Should I report it somewhere to stackexchange developers or is there a workaround and I got an error somewhere in the markdown and the software is fine? Or should I just edit and re-save the question?
I'm using "firefox developers" 133.0b8. Thanks.

The post in question seems to be working for me after an edit which added an empty line before the text containing the URL.
Compare revision 2 and revision 1. (Feel free to revert the edit if you want to illustrate the problem.)

On meta you can find several posts showing that combining HTML and MarkDown can sometimes cause problems. I think that this might have been the culprit here, too.
I used the same picture as you - once with the HTML syntax taken from your post and once using Markdown. The second one seems to be working.
<img src="https://i.sstatic.net/oUstI.png" />
[Crux Vol. 1, No. 7](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=1&issue=7)


[Crux Vol. 1, No. 7](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=1&issue=7)
![Triangle ABC and segments AP, BP, CP](https://i.sstatic.net/oUstI.png)
[Crux Vol. 1, No. 7](https://cms.math.ca/publications/crux/issue/?volume=1&issue=7)


Crux Vol. 1, No. 7

Thanks for pointing out the possible issue and for editing the post to eliminate the problem.
